# Javascript and keyup to pass data to a Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

My view has a single textbox which captures scans from users.  The scans will then be passed without any further user action to another action that will then use the scanned data to complete the transaction.  So far, the textbox gets populated with the scan and immediately does redirect but without the contents of the textbox.  This is what I have;

View:

```
<input id="thisText" class="largetext" name="txtScanLabel"  onkeyup="myKeyUp" />
```

And:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var tResults = "Test";

       $(function () {
           $('input.largetext').focus();
       });

       $(function () {
           $("#thisText").keyup(myKeyUp);
       });

       function myKeyUp(eventInstance) {
           var myURL = '@Url.Action("ScanResults", "Home")';
           window.location.href = myURL + '?tResults' + encodeURIComponent(tResults);
       }

   </script>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult ScanResults(string tResults)
    {

        var test = tResults;                     

        return RedirectToAction("Success");

    }
```

Comment: why multiple `ready` handlers

Comment: is tResults in controller action null?

Comment: @3nigma, this doesn't matter. jQuery is intelligent enough to merge all of them into a single handler executed when the DOM is ready.

Comment: Is EVERY keyup designed to fire the event?  What if they press and hold a key?
What if they press a ctrl-v sequence and never let go?

Comment: tResults is null, I was just using a hardcoded value to determine if the issue was with the input from the textbox.  There is a single textbox on the page, designed for a scanner only, no entry from operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have unobtrusively subscribed to the `.keyup` event handler with jQuery and yet you have used the `onkeyup` attribute in your DOM. You don't need to do those two things. Using jQuery is enough. So start by cleaning your markup:

```
<input id="thisText" class="largetext" name="txtScanLabel" />
```

Also you have hardcoded the `tResults` value to `Test` in your javascript. Instead of using this hardcoded value from the global variable (that you could get rid of) you should read the value from the textbox:

```
function myKeyUp(eventInstance) {
    var myURL = '@Url.Action("ScanResults", "Home")';
    var value = $(this).val();
    window.location.href = myURL + '?tResults=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
}
```

Notice that using `window.location.href` will immediately redirect to the `ScanResults` controller action when the user types something into the input field. You probably want to use AJAX:

```
function myKeyUp(eventInstance) {
    var myURL = '@Url.Action("ScanResults", "Home")';
    $.ajax({
        url: myURL,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { tResults: $(this).val() },
        success: function(result) {
            // do something with the result returned by the controller action
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I started with AJAX but it was not working either.  I removed the hardcoded test value but I'm still not seeing any data returned to the ScanResults controller action.

Comment: Did you notice the missing `=` sign after the `tResults` query string parameter that your forgot: `'?tResults='`.

Comment: Ahh, nuts.  That's exactly what it was.  Sorry to waste everyone's time!

Answer (score 0):

you haven't included [HttpPost] Attribute in controler Action.

Comment: He is redirecting to it (`window.location.href`). A redirect means GET verb, not POST. If he decorates the controller action with the `[HttpPost]` attribute he will never be able to redirect to it.

Comment: but he want pass data to that URL.is it possible with GET?

Answer (score 0):

You need this perhaps as your "test will NOT work as it is now:

```
       window.location.href = myURL + '?tResults' + encodeURIComponent(tResults);
```

change to

```
       tResults = $('#thisText').val();
       window.location.href = myURL + '?tResults=' + encodeURIComponent(tResults);
```

DO NOT forget that important equal sign in there.